# In Outlook, how can I identify exceptions to an appointment series?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I created a recurring appointment (series) in Outlook 2013, then modified one future occurrence and stored some important notes in it. As it happens, I need those notes now (instead of on the future date where I stored them), but I don't know which date / which occurrence in the series is the exception where I stored them.

(This appointment recurs daily, and for all I know the notes are in an occurrence more than a year away. Plus, I cannot remember specific keywords in the notes. Therefore I don't think search will help, and I am trying to avoid manually opening every occurrence.)

Is there any other way to identify which occurrence in this series has been modified? The closest thing I found on the web is [this article](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/find-text-in-appointment-exceptions), which is a slightly different use case and doesn't help.

Comment: You'll visually see a hatch mark across the recurring icon. You can try right click on Calendar, Share, Email Calendar. Select full details and try whole calendar. If you have more than 10 years, then select a date range. See if the HTML inserted into the e-mail has the details you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sun](https://superuser.com/users/164425/sun)'s comment didn't quite work for me, but it did put me on the right track.

I opened the series, then selected `Forward > Forward as iCalendar`. Then, from the draft message that opened with the iCalendar attachment, I saved the attachment and opened it with a text editor.

Within that text file, you can search for `X-ALT-DESC` and/or `DESCRIPTION` attributes which carry the notes made on any item in the series that has been edited separately.